# Sort direct neighbor nodes (books) by attribute of 2nd degree neighbors (authors) for user book list?

Tags: sorting, graph, arangodb, graph-traversal, aql

<sup>By agheranimesh via Slack:</sup>

This is my graph, named *LibraryGraph*:

[image: LibraryGraph]

My graph query:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND "User/001" GRAPH "LibraryGraph"
   SORT p.vertices[2].Name
   RETURN  p.vertices[1]
```

It's not giving me result I want. I want a book list **sorted by author name** and books without author should come last (B2, B3, B1, B4, B5).

Script to re-create the data (`arangosh --javascript.execute <file>`):

```
db._createDatabase('Library')
db._useDatabase('Library')

const User = db._create('User')
const Book = db._create('Book')
const Author = db._create('Author')

const User_Book = db._createEdgeCollection('User_Book')
const Book_Author = db._createEdgeCollection('Book_Author')

User.save({ '_key': '001', 'UserName': 'U1' })

Book.save({ '_key': 'B1', 'Name': 'B1' })
Book.save({ '_key': 'B2', 'Name': 'B2' })
Book.save({ '_key': 'B3', 'Name': 'B3' })
Book.save({ '_key': 'B4', 'Name': 'B4' })
Book.save({ '_key': 'B5', 'Name': 'B5' })

Author.save({ '_key': 'A', 'Name': 'A' })
Author.save({ '_key': 'B', 'Name': 'B' })
Author.save({ '_key': 'X', 'Name': 'X' })
Author.save({ '_key': 'Y', 'Name': 'Y' })
Author.save({ '_key': 'Z', 'Name': 'Z' })

User_Book.save({ '_from': 'User/001', '_to': 'Book/B1' })
User_Book.save({ '_from': 'User/001', '_to': 'Book/B2' })
User_Book.save({ '_from': 'User/001', '_to': 'Book/B3' })
User_Book.save({ '_from': 'User/001', '_to': 'Book/B4' })
User_Book.save({ '_from': 'User/001', '_to': 'Book/B5' })

Book_Author.save({ '_from': 'Book/B2', '_to': 'Author/A' })
Book_Author.save({ '_from': 'Book/B3', '_to': 'Author/B' })
Book_Author.save({ '_from': 'Book/B1', '_to': 'Author/X' })
Book_Author.save({ '_from': 'Book/B1', '_to': 'Author/Y' })
Book_Author.save({ '_from': 'Book/B1', '_to': 'Author/Z' })

const graph_module =  require('org/arangodb/general-graph')
const graph = graph_module._create('LibraryGraph')

graph._addVertexCollection('User')
graph._addVertexCollection('Book')
graph._addVertexCollection('Author')

graph._extendEdgeDefinitions(graph_module._relation('User_Book', ['User'], ['Book']))
graph._extendEdgeDefinitions(graph_module._relation('Book_Author', ['Book'], ['Author']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a single traversal with variable depth (1..2) to cover both cases, books with and without authors, I suggest to use two traversals:

```
FOR book IN OUTBOUND "User/001" GRAPH "LibraryGraph"
    LET author = FIRST(
        FOR author IN OUTBOUND book._id GRAPH "LibraryGraph"
            SORT author.Name
            LIMIT 1
            RETURN author.Name
    ) OR "\uFFFF"
    SORT author
    RETURN book
```

First we traverse from `User/001` to the linked books. Then we do a second traversal from each book to the linked authors. This may return 0, 1 or multiple authors. The sub-query caps the result to the alphabetically first author (e.g. X out of X, Y, Z) and returns the name.

In the scope of the main query, we take the author name or fallback to a value that ends up last if sorted (`null` would end up first, which is not desired here). Then we sort the books by author name and return them:

[image: Query result]

Another way to achieve this result, yet harder to understand:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 OUTBOUND "User/001" GRAPH "LibraryGraph"
    LET name = p.vertices[2].Name OR "\uFFFF"
    COLLECT book = p.vertices[1] AGGREGATE author = MIN(name)
    SORT author
    RETURN book
```

The traversal returns paths with 2 or 3 vertices...

```
   [0]         [1]         [2]
User/001 --> Book/B2
User/001 --> Book/B2 --> Author/A
User/001 --> Book/B3
User/001 --> Book/B3 --> Author/B
User/001 --> Book/B4
User/001 --> Book/B5
User/001 --> Book/B1
User/001 --> Book/B1 --> Author/Y
User/001 --> Book/B1 --> Author/X
User/001 --> Book/B1 --> Author/Z
```

The authors at index 2 (`p.vertices[2]`) or a fallback value is temporarily stored in a variable `name`. Then the book vertices are grouped together to eliminate duplicates (caused by the variable traversal depth, which returns e.g. `001-->B2` but also the longer path `001-->B2-->A`).

Aggregation is used to pick the author name with the lowest value (`MIN`), which usually means the alphabetically first - it probably doesn't work correctly for some languages and character sets however, whereas `SORT` does sort correctly based on the rules of the set language (can only be one per DBMS instance).

The grouping result - distinct book documents - is sorted by author names and returned.